# solr configuration on jetty container

Tags: java, search, solr, jetty

In my case, indexing is done but its not giving any result by text search. It is showing general indexed data by giving `*:*` as search term.

solrconfig.xml :

```
`<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>`
```

schema.xml :

```
`<field name="su_id"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/> 
  <field name="su_url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="su_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="su_actual_url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
   <defaultSearchField>su_path</defaultSearchField>`
```

data-config.xml :

```
`<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
          driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prod_astra" 
          user="root" 
          password="xyz"/>    

  <document name="content">
    <entity name="products" 
        query="select * from search_links">
        <field column="su_id" name="su_id" />
        <field column="su_path" name="id"/>
        <field column="su_url" name="su_url"/>
    <field column="su_actual_url" name="su_actual_url" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q=*:*` searches for all content on all the documents, hence you get back the results.

`q=something` will search for something on the default search field, which is usually text if you have not modified the schema.xml.

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

You can change the default field to be the field you want to search on.
OR use specific field to search on the specific field e.g. su_url q=su_url:url

If you want to search on multiple field, you can combine the fields into one field by using copyfields or use [dismax request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to search on su_path field. One of its column value is '->home furnishings->home furnishings->featured categories->Bed & Bath'. I tried q= above value and tried also with separate words of that value but the response is zero.

Comment: your fields are all string which will not be tokenised and analyzed. Change them to text and the search should work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jayendra. I changed them to text. Now its working fine. Some times its not giving result for `*:*` but finally got the solution.